# Why does Dict(5:2) not throw an error in Julia?

Tags: julia

It seems like I shouldn't be able to write `Dict(5:3)` in Julia (no error is returned). Or `Dict(1:-1:3)`. Or anytime the first number is larger than the second is smaller than the third. Is this a bug? Defining a dictionary by a UnitRange really doesn't make much sense. Or am I just not understanding how Julia is interpreting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Dict` constructor just uses what's often referred to as "duck-typing" — it doesn't explicitly look at what it is passed, it just tries to use it as it'd expect:

```
help?> Dict
# ...
  Given a single iterable argument, constructs a Dict whose key-value pairs
  are taken from 2-tuples (key,value) generated by the argument.
```

You're passing it an empty iterable, so this constructs an empty dictionary.

This case is indeed a little strange in that we know more than just the fact that it's an empty iterable. We know that it's an array, we know the concrete element type, and we know that if it had any elements, it'd definitely error. At the same time it is an empty collection, and I'd expect empty collections to create empty dictionaries.